# 【Rails】親テーブルのデータを子テーブルの検索したデータの個数で並び替える方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Railsでactiverecordから出力する順番を変える方法を悩んでいます。

下記のように
親テーブル-post
子テーブル-likeは関連付けの関係にあります。

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post
 has_many :likes
end

#app/models/like.rb
class Like
 belongs_to :Post
end
```

やりたいことは昨日作られたlikeが多い順にPostを並び替えるということをやりたいのですが、
やり方がわかりません。

単純にlikeが多い順にpostを並び変えるということは下記のようにできました。

```
Post.joins(:likes).group('posts.id').order('COUNT(likes.id) DESC').limit(100)
```

これに昨日作られたlikeで並び替えるにはどのように変更したらよいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

「昨日作られたlikeで並び替える」のであれば、こんなコードはどうでしょうか？

```
Post.
  joins(:likes).
  group('posts.id').
  order("SUM(CASE WHEN likes.created_at BETWEEN '2015-04-07 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-07 23:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC").
  limit(100)
```

where句ではないので、おそらく日付の文字列は直接文字列として埋め込む必要があると思います。（もしくはDB上のシステム日付とDB関数をあれこれ駆使して「昨日の開始日時と終了日時」を作り出すとか）
エラーが出たり思ったような結果が得られなかったりする場合はアプリで使っているRDBMSを教えてください。

### 追伸

上のコードでは日時を文字列として渡していますが、そもそもタイムゾーンをきちんと考慮しないと意図した期間を指定できません。
また、タイムゾーンはRails、OS、DBの設定に依存するため画一的な回答を書くことはできません。
詳しくはこちらの記事を参考にしてみてください。

- http://qiita.com/joker1007/items/2c277cca5bd50e4cce5e
- http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/cae89ee43c30f5d6fa2c

Comment: ありがとうございます！
いただいたコードは無事に動きました。
ただやはり、日時を関数で表示させたいのです。

現状タイムゾーンは全て下記の記事を参考に日本時間に設定しています。
http://qiita.com/norifumi-y@github/items/fbc89daa2206cd6f75d1

もし可能ならば助言いただけますと幸いです。
※追記を確認いたしました。本当にご丁寧にありがとうございます！

Comment: 上記下記のようにPost.
joins(:likes).  
group('posts.id').  
order("SUM(CASE WHEN likes.created_at BETWEEN (now() - interval 1 day) AND now() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC").  
limit(100)  

に書いてみました。